# Highcharts - legend titles rotation is not working fine in IE10

Tags: highcharts, rotation, internet-explorer-10, legend

Highcharts -Legend titles rotation is not working in IE10. 
We have seen that the they are rendered in different HTML tags :

- In FF27=> they are rendered using **g** and **text** elements  (http://i62.tinypic.com/8x0h39.png)
- In IE10=> they are rendered using **div** and **expand** elements (http://i60.tinypic.com/ft6hu.png)

Someone could help us to fix this in IE10?

Many thanks in advance :)

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: Labels rotation: this [example from Highcharts](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/xaxis/labels-rotation/) is working without problem.

Comment: Have you any live demo?

Comment: Thanks to everybody, the problem was the X-UA-Compatible header, which was forcing IE=EmulateIE7.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you are setting X-UA-Compatible attribute in the metatag.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE9" />
```

If this is less than IE9, the rotated labels wont display properly.

Comment: Thanks a lot user1245717, the problem was the X-UA-Compatible header, which was forcing IE=EmulateIE7.